# jquery datetimepicker.js position issue if it in div panel overflow auto

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

please help on below scenario issue:
[image]
 Calendar position issue: suppose if i place the  inside the panel which is have some height with overflow auto property "" when we click on the calendar and then while we scrolling the div scroller the calendar is seems like fixed position instead of goes along with the input !!!! any soln[image]

Comment: provide your html and css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually without looking at the code,i can not explain the issue, 
you can add following css for that
calender position abosolute,
if is not work float:left/ display:inline
try this things and let us know

Comment: Iam using the default jquery.datepicker.css and the html is as like below: <div style="border:1px solid red; height: 600px; overflow:auto; ">


<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

 <h3>DateTimePicker</h3>
 <input type="date"  class="datetimepicker"/><br><br> </div>   i.e when i have the input within any div which have overflow auto, i am getting like above issue... got it? please check this plugin: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/